# Replace a link with text content from other a link – abstracting code

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, code-snippets

So I have a function where the text of one div replaces another,
I got the code working fine, however I wonder if there is a nice dynamic way to abstract the code so I get a shorter snippet, and thus I don't have to repeat the code over and over for each "pair" of divs?

My JS:

```
 var correctAnswer1 = $('#q1').text();              
    $('#c1').text(correctAnswer1);

    var correctAnswer2 = $('#q2').text();               
    $('#c2').text(correctAnswer2);

    var correctAnswer3 = $('#q3').text();               
    $('#c3').text(correctAnswer3);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you allready know the number of pairs you coud do something like this:

```
var numberOfQuestions = 5;

for(i = 0; i < numberOfQuestions; i++)
{

    var answer = jQuery("#q"+i).text();

    jQuery("#c"+i).text(answer);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give all the `#qN` elements the `question` class.

```
$(".question").each(function () {
    var cid = "#c"+$(this).attr("id").substr(1);
    $(cid).text($(this).text());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i this this will work

```
function setTxtVal(id){
if(typeof id == "string"){
var sec = id.charAt(id.length - 1);
$("#c"+sec).text( $("#"+id).text() )
}
if(typeof id == "object"){
var x ,s;
for (x in id) {
var s = x.charAt(x.length - 1);
$("#c"+s).text( $("#"+x).text() )    
}
}

setTextVal("c1")
```

or

```
setTextVal(["c1", "c3", "c4"])
```

or u can make a jquery plugin

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[id^=q]').each(function(index){
  $('#c' + index).html($(this).html());
});
```

Somtething like this